# Run all posible combination of linear regression with 2 independent variables

Tags: r

I want to run every combination possible for every 2 independent variables (OLS regression). I have a csv where I have my data (just one dependent variable and 23 independent variables), and I've tried renaming the variables inside my database from a to z, and I called 'y' to my dependent variable (a column with name "y" which is my dependent variable) to be recognized by the following code:

```
#all the combinations
all_comb <- combn(letters, 2)

#create the formulas from the combinations above and paste
text_form <- apply(all_comb, 2, function(x) paste('Y ~', paste0(x, collapse = '+')))

lapply(text_form, function(i) lm(i, data= KOFS05.12))
```

but this error is shown:

> `Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'y' not found`

I need to know the R squared

Any idea to make it work and run every possible regression?

Comment: Do you have a column called `Y` or `y` ? Can you edit your post to include first few rows of your data using `dput` i.e `dput(head(KOFS05.12))` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments under the question check whether you need y or Y.  Having addressed that we can use any of these. There is no need to rename the columns.  We use the built in `mtcars` data set as an example since no test data was provided in the question. (Please always provide that in the future.)

**1) ExhaustiveSearch** This runs quite fast so you might be able to try combinations higher than 2 as well.

```
library(ExhaustiveSearch)
ExhaustiveSearch(mpg ~., mtcars, combsUpTo = 2)
```

**2) combn**   Use the `lmfun` function defined below with `combn`.

```
dep <- "mpg"  # name of dependent variable
nms <- setdiff(names(mtcars), dep)  # names of indep variables
lmfun <- function(x, dep) do.call("lm", list(reformulate(x, dep), quote(mtcars)))

lms <- combn(nms, 2, lmfun, dep = dep, simplify = FALSE)
names(lms) <- lapply(lms, formula)
```

**3) listcompr** Using `lmfun` from above and listcompr we can use the following. Note that we need version 0.1.1 or later of listcompr which is not yet on CRAN so we get it from github.

```
# install.github("patrickroocks/listcompr")
library(listcompr)
packageVersion("listcompr") # need version 0.1.1 or later

dep <- "mpg"  # name of dependent variable
nms <- setdiff(names(mtcars), dep)  # names of indep variables

lms2 <- gen.named.list("{nm1}.{nm2}", lmfun(c(nm1, nm2), dep), 
  nm1 = nms, nm2 = nms, nm1 < nm2)
```

Comment: Thank you!!! ExhaustiveSearch and Akaike method solved my problem looking for the best statistical significance

Answer (score 1):

You should specify your `text_form` as formulas:

```r
KOFS05.12 <- data.frame(y = rnorm(10),
                        a = rnorm(10),
                        b = rnorm(10),
                        c = rnorm(10))

all_comb <- combn(letters[1:3], 2)
fmla_form <- apply(all_comb, 2, function(x) as.formula(sprintf("y ~ %s", paste(x, collapse = "+"))))
lapply(fmla_form, function(i) lm(i, KOFS05.12))
#> [[1]]
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = i, data = KOFS05.12)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)            a            b  
#>     0.19763     -0.15873      0.02854  
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = i, data = KOFS05.12)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)            a            c  
#>     0.21395     -0.15967      0.05737  
#> 
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = i, data = KOFS05.12)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)            b            c  
#>    0.157140     0.002523     0.028088
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: `as.formula` is not necessary. It would still work and give the same output if you remove it.